# EfficientNet and MobileNetV2 models from TensorFlow.Keras not being reproducible on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mobilenet, efficientnet

After downloading an **EfficientNet** model from [tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/efficientnet), and retraining it on our own data, I've noticed that the results are not reproducible. The results are reproducible for other architectures like **VGG16**, **ResNet101**, **InceptionV3**, and **InceptionResNetV2**, but not for any of the **EfficientNetBx** models.

Layer by layer analysis shows that the `DepthwiseConv2D` layer is producing different gradients. I also tried the **MobileNetV2** which has the same type of layers, and it is NOT reproducible either. I wonder if anyone else has encountered this issue and how they have solved it.

Please note that I've set all the following seeds, and even have tensorflow-determinism:

```
random.seed(1)
np.random.seed(1)
tf.random.set_seed(1)
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = TRUE
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = TRUE
```

TensorFlow Version: `tensorflow-gpu==2.3`

Opened this issue on Tensorflow GitHub:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47174